# Definition of $d (P (x ,y )dx)$

Tags: differential-geometry

I know it is defined as $ dP \wedge dx  $ or explicitly,

$$ \frac{\partial P }{\partial y } dy \wedge dx   . $$

The question is, could it be $dx \wedge d P $?  Or

$$  \frac{\partial P }{\partial y }  dx \wedge dy ?    $$

Comment: How is it related to Mathematica ?

Comment: Sorry, it should be another forum

Comment: Could anyone delete it?

Comment: $dx\wedge dy=-dy\wedge dx$.